# DeQuervain's Tensynovitis

Tags: electric-bass-guitar, health

This question is for anyone with experience coming back from DeQuervain's. I have had this problem for a few months and generally things have gotten better. I'm noticing a bit of soreness when I go back to playing my bass. Is a bit of soreness normal? For example, yesterday I worked on some scales for about 5 minutes and was a bit sore after. This morning the soreness is pretty much gone.

Thanks.

Comment: And why a vote to close for *unclear what you're asking*? There's a question mark, it's not deeply buried, and the words before it form a great question: "**Is a bit of soreness normal?**"

Comment: You should be talking to a doctor about health issues.

Comment: @MatthewRead true, and this is going to be opinionated of me, but dealing with rock climbing injuries, etc., comparing anecdotes with people experienced in the field can be extremely elucidating. Doctors tend to tell you to just stop doing whatever thing, when sometimes the patient wants a better understanding of the risk, which the collective community will understand better.

Answer (score 1):

(My remarks will be based on general problems of this type, not specifically on De Quervain, which I don't have any experience with.)

It sounds like you're doing the right thing by getting back into your music very gently.

If it starts to hurt right off the bat, don't play.  Also, if the soreness takes more than an hour or two to go away, then something probably isn't right, and it's time to see a doctor or a physical therapist

Comment: I upvoted because I *think* this tends to be sound "common sense" for reacting to injuries or soreness.